# Rendering Too Many Images in Canvas Element

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, byte

I'm using an HTML5 canvas element to render bytes as an image and am having an issue of TOO MANY images rendering.

These bytes are not encoded as an image (PNG, JPEG). They are just the bytes.

I can make the image render with the code I have, but it renders 4 images width wise and doesn't fill the entirety of the canvas.

Here is my JS code (`res` is the bytes being passed):

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
canvas.width = 940;
canvas.height = 470;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var imageData = ctx.createImageData(940,470);
var data = imageData.data;

for(var i = 0; i < res.length; i+= 4){
  data[i] = res[i];
data[i + 1] = res [i + 1];
data[i + 2] = res [i + 2];
data[i + 3] = res [i + 3];
}

ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
```

And the HTML canvas element:

```
<canvas id='myCanvas' width='940' height='470'></canvas>
```

Comment: Hi, the element id is `myCanvas` and you get it with `mycanvas` not the same letter case

Comment: Sounds like the res array image is at a different resolution. Try changing the canvas size to 1/4 eg `canvas.width = 235` **OR** it could be that the res data is only grey scale with one byte per pixel so try `data[i] = data[i+1] = data[i+2] = res[i /4]; data[i+3] = 255;`

Comment: @Abderlrahman, oops! Typo that I fixed.

Comment: @Blindman67, that was it! It was a grayscale image. Totally didn't realize that was relevant since I'm so new to all of this. Really interesting stuff. Make an answer so I can mark that correct. Thank you so much!